# Setting "Domain controller" of the active-directory plugin in jenkins via groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am configuring the active-directory plugin in jenkins via groovy like this:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.security.*
import hudson.plugins.active_directory.*

def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
String domain = "MY-DOMAIN.DE"
String site = ""
String server = "my-server:3268"
String bindName = ""
String bindPassword = ""
adrealm = new ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm(domain, site, bindName, bindPassword, server, GroupLookupStrategy.RECURSIVE)
instance.setSecurityRealm(adrealm)
```

It works. But the "Domain controller" is not set.

[image]

I was hoping, that the "server" would set it, but no.
How can I set this via groovy script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backward compatibility of the constructor is failing, please use latest constructor (more here https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39676 ):

```
 @DataBoundConstructor
    // as Java signature, this binding doesn't make sense, so please don't use this constructor
    public ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm(String domain, List<ActiveDirectoryDomain> domains, String site, String bindName,
                                        String bindPassword, String server, GroupLookupStrategy groupLookupStrategy, boolean removeIrrelevantGroups, Boolean customDomain, CacheConfiguration cache) {
```

And the example:

```
import hudson.plugins.active_directory.* 
import jenkins.model.*

def instance = Jenkins.getInstance();
def ActiveDirectoryDomain adDomain = new ActiveDirectoryDomain("Example_Domain_Name_2", "Example_Domain_Controller_2");
def domains = new ArrayList<ActiveDirectoryDomain>();
domains.add(adDomain);

def securityRealm = new ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm( 
"", 
domains,
"", 
"",
"",  
"", 
GroupLookupStrategy.RECURSIVE,
false,
true,
null)
println(securityRealm.domains)

instance.setSecurityRealm(securityRealm) 
instance.save()
```

Works for me!